# Residual learning in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, deep-residual-networks

[image: inception layer]

I am attempting to replicate this image from a research paper. In the image, the orange arrow indicates a shortcut using residual learning and the layer outlined in red indicates a dilated convolution.

In the code below, r5 is the result of the relu seen in the image. I have excluded the code between the relu and the dilation layer for simplicity.  **In tensorflow, how would I properly combine the result of the relu and dilated convolution to execute the residual shortcut?**

```
#relu layer
r5 = tf.nn.relu(layer5)
...
#dilation layer
h_conv4 = conv3d_dilation(concat1, 1154)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image is quite straight forward - it says you should **add** them, so:

```
#relu layer
r5 = tf.nn.relu(layer5)
...
#dilation layer
h_conv4 = conv3d_dilation(concat1, 1154)

#combined
combined = r5 + h_conv4
```

Comment: If you had a moment, I had a second question. This is the architecture I am attempting to replicate: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1qLP2.png From this information, is there any way to tell the number of output channels for the deconvolutions?

Comment: It depends on the shape of `r5`, it's fairly possible that it needs a projection - https://stackoverflow.com/q/46121283/712995

Comment: @lejlot This is a 3d image, so P is actually referring to the 3rd dimension not number of channels